# Using Python for Compounding Interest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing a test that returns the interest total by year. How can I append the values of interest as it compounds on each step inside of the array `interest = []` in my Investor class? For some reason this has been difficult to wrap my head around.

**Code:**

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

'''Represents my test case(s) for the dojo.'''

def setUp(self):
    '''Defines the initial state of an investor.'''
    self.investor = Investor(10000, 7.2, 5)

def test_solve_for_interest(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.investor.get_interest(), 720.0)

def test_get_interest_by_year(self):
    '''Returns a value of interest associated by the year.'''
    self.assertEqual(self.investor.interest_by_year(1), 10720.0)


class Investor(object):

    def __init__(self, amount, rate, time):
        self.amount = amount
        self.rate = rate
        self.time = time

    def get_interest(self):
        return (self.amount * self.rate) / 100.0

    def interest_by_year(self, year):
        interest = []
        for i in xrange(1, (self.time+1)):
            # collect compounding interest each year
        return interest[year]
```

**Expected Results:**

```
year 1 = 10,720.00 (interest[1])

year 2 = 11491.84  (interest[2])

year 3 = 12319.25  (interest[3])

year 4 = 13206.24  (interest[4])

year 5 = 14157.09  (interest[5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def interest_by_year(self, year):
    interest = [self.amount]
    for i in xrange(self.time):
        interest.append(interest[i]*self.rate)
    return interest[year]
```

---

Test:

```
ivt = Investor(10000, 1.072, 10)
for i in range(1, 6):
    print "year", i, "=", ivt.interest_by_year(i)
```

Output:

```
year 1 = 10720.0
year 2 = 11491.84
year 3 = 12319.25248
year 4 = 13206.2386586
year 5 = 14157.087842
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting an error of ```AssertionError: 72000.0 != 10720.0```

Comment: So that my code calculate the first year interest as 72000.0? Did you input the right rate?

Comment: For test_get_interest_by_yearself.assertEqual(self.investor.interest_by_year(1), 10720.0)

Comment: I see, but as my test, `intest_by_year(1)` did output 10720. So I wonder that do you set the rate=1.072 right?

Comment: I initialized it with 7.2, so I would need to convert that by dividing by 100 and then adding 1.0. Also, could you explain the logic behind this? This was supposed to be a quick dojo to warm up with but it caused me quite some trouble putting together that last part.

Comment: First put the amount as `interest[0]`, and then each `interest[i+1]` should be `interest[i] * rate`. Append it one by one.

Comment: If you want to set the rate in the way of 7.2, then just make it to be `interest[i] * (1+self.rate/100.0)` in the `interest_by_year` function.

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved more elegantly with Pandas:

```
years = range(1,6)
rate = 0.072
rates = pandas.Series(index = years, data = rate)
```

Note that the rate may differ over the years

```
initialValue*((rates + 1).cumprod())
```